# configure factories for nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

anyone passed through this?

the scene is a nested form on user creation, where:

1. User has_one Profile
2. Profile belongs_to user

so my factory is configured in this way but when i run the test aways bring me this result:

```
 Failure/Error: user_attributes[:user_attributes][:profile_attributes] = Factory.attributes_for :profile
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

**Factory**

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.after_build do |user|  
    f.email                 'exemple@exemple.com'
    f.password              'password'
    f.password_confirmation 'password'  
    user.profile ||= Factory.build(:profile, :user => user)
  end
end

Factory.define :profile do |f| 
  f.after_build do |profile|
    profile.user ||= Factory.build(:user, :profile => profile)

  f.nome          'alguem'
  f.sobrenome     'alguem'
  f.endereco      'rua x'
  f.numero        '95'
  f.genero        'm'
  f.complemento   'casa'
  f.bairro        'bairro x'
  f.cidade        'cidade x'
  f.estado        'estado x'
  f.cep           '232323'


end

end
```

**Users_spec**

```
describe "CreateUsers" do

    before :each do

      user_attributes = Factory.attributes_for :user
      user_attributes[:user_attributes][:profile_attributes] = Factory.attributes_for :profile

    @user = User.new(user_attributes)

    end
```

Comment: Can you try to raise user_attributes.inspect before you try to assign the user_attributes[:user_attributes][:profile_attributes]?  Your error is telling you that user_attributes[:user_attributes] is nil, and so when you try to index on it with [:profile_attributes], you're using a method, []=, on a nil value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to auto create a profile when you create a user then try building it this way, using the new FactoryGirl syntax:

Factory file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email                 'exemple@exemple.com'
    password              'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
    after_build do |profile|
      user.profile << FactoryGirl.build(:profile, :user => user)
    end
  end

  factory :profile do
    nome          'alguem'
    sobrenome     'alguem'
    endereco      'rua x'
    numero        '95'
    genero        'm'
    complemento   'casa'
    bairro        'bairro x'
    cidade        'cidade x'
    estado        'estado x'
    cep           '232323'
    user
  end
end
```

Note the addition of `user` in the profile factory with defines the association on the profile record. Provided your user factory is called `:user` you do not have to pass any arguments.

You should then be able to call

```
@user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
```

and it will build both a user and a profile. You can see the profile by calling `@user.profile`.

If you call `@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)` it will create both the user and the profile, inserting the `user_id` into the profile record.